# all functions in one script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I put all my .js files in one. So one page will use less than 10% of the functions there.

eg, page1.php need only .func1, but now I have func 2, 3, 4...

```
$(document).on("click", ".func1", function() { /* ... */ });
$(document).on("click", ".func2", function() { /* ... */ });
$(document).on("click", ".func3", function() { /* ... */ });
$(document).on("click", ".func4", function() { /* ... */ });
$(document).click(function(){ /* ... */ });
... fun20, func30.
```

Is it ok? I need only func1 but all this others listeners are working too. any thing I need or should do?

Comment: Make the selectors more specific, eg. `body.home .func1`, `body.foo .func2` etc.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan for some it will be a good idea, but others I use in many pages, eg, func 1, I use in page 1 and page 2...

Comment: So are you asking how you can make the JS file smaller?

Comment: You can make function and call them through attribute like onClick

Comment: Unless these event handlers are interfering with each other (one being the child of other, etc), I don't see this being a bad design at all, especially if some of their code is common and can be refactored. But it is almost impossible to tell one way or the other without looking at your actual code.

Comment: @gurvinder372 thank you friend, it is what I'd like to know.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with your code but definitely it can get better.

There are some ways in order to do that :

**1. Use a code bundler like webpack**

Using webpack would be a good Idea specially for it's new feature [**Code Splitting**](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/) that let's you to import different modules dynamically.

**2. Using Modular design patterns like [Revealing Module Pattern](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript)**

There are someways to do this and it's so easy. I put some example codes for you down below :

```js
// Self Invoke function
var Module1 = (function(){

    // Configurations
    var config = {
        body : '.body',
        header : '.header',
        ...
    }

    // Functions
    function bodyHandler(){
        ...
    }

    function headerHandler(){
        ...
    }

    // Bind Events
    $(document).on('click', config.body ,  bodyHandler);
    $(document).on('click', config.header ,  headerHandler);

})()
```

You can separate your JavaScript code into various modules and use them in different pages.

Also you can config each module dynamically from outside (In html page for instance) like so :

```js
(function(){

    var Page = {
        // Init the Module with your own configuration
        init(conf){
            this.config = conf;
            this.bindEvents()
        },

        // Bind Events
        bindEvents(){
            $(document).on('click', this.config.body ,  this.bodyHandler);
            $(document).on('click', this.config.header ,  this.headerHandler);
        },

        bodyHandler(){
            ...
        },

        headerHandler(){
            ...
        },
        
    }

    // You can Init the module whereever you want
    Page.init({
        body : '.body',
        header : '.header',
        // Other options ...
    })
        
})()
```

Answer (score 1):

I currently have a similar process when it comes to JavaScript. All functions I write go into one large file. I then have a single function that runs when the DOM is ready that binds events onto specific elements.

By doing it that way a) I know where all the event binding is happening and b) Only events that are specific to the content of the page are actually bound

for example....

```
(function() {

    function fnFunctionA() { ... }
    function fnFunctionB() { ... }
    function fnFunctionC() { ... }

    $('.containerA').on('click', '.subElementA', fnFunctionA);
    $('.containerB').on('click', '.subElementB', fnFunctionB);
    $('.containerC').on('click', '.subElementC', fnFunctionC);

}());
```

Function A is only ever bound when containerA actually exists on the page and so on and so forth